# Passing multiple variables into JavaScript function in Template Literals (DOM)

Tags: javascript, dom

I am looping through an array of objects (rendering data coming from an API) via Vanilla JavaScript (DOM). And I want to pass more than one value (Product ID, Product Name .. etc) to a function triggered in the event of a click button.  **saveProduct(${proInfo})** as it shown below (proInfo is an object).

The problem is I have been able to pass ONLY ONE value to this function. I tried to pass the variable as an object but it didn't work and got the error **(index):1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input**

```
var shopNcounter = 0;
const baseURL = "***";
const idsArray = [];
const divRow = document.querySelector(".row");
const buttonContainer = document.querySelector("#button-container")
//create column div
function createDiv() {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.classList.add("col-xl-3");
    div.classList.add("col-md-6");
    div.classList.add("col-sm-12");
    return div;
}



async function getData(id) {
        shopNcounter ++;
        console.log(shopNcounter);
        if(shopNcounter > 5) {
            getProInfo(id);
            return;
        } else if (shopNcounter > 4) {
            getProducts(id);
            return;
        }
        idsArray.push(id);
        console.log(id);
        console.log(idsArray);
        if(idsArray.length > 10) {
            idsArray.splice(0,6);
        }
        const api = `**shop=${shopNcounter}&id=${id}`;
        try {
            const response = await fetch(api);
            const data = await response.json();
            divRow.innerHTML = "";
            if (shopNcounter > 1) {
                buttonContainer.innerHTML = `
                    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-warning px-5" onclick="moveBack(${idsArray[idsArray.length-2]})">رجوع</button>

                `
            } else {
                buttonContainer.innerHTML = "";
            }
                //mapping through data
            data.map(item => {
                
                    const div = createDiv();
                    divRow.appendChild(div);
                    div.innerHTML+=`
                    <div class="card text-center h-100 mx-auto border-white shadow" style="width: 16rem;">
                        <img src="${baseURL + item.image}" class="card-img-top mx-auto" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        
                        <a onclick=handleClick(${item.id}) class="btn btn-outline-dark px-5 mt-4" id="goToItemButton">${item.name}</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    `;
            });
        } catch(error) {console.log(error);}
        
    }
getData(0);

async function getProducts(id) {

    //shop > 4 = 5

    console.log("Get Product is being executing");
    const apiProducts = `**product?id=${id}`;

    try {
        const response = await fetch(apiProducts);
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        divRow.innerHTML = "";
       
        //mapping through data
        data.map((item, index) => {
             var proInfo = {
               pid: item.PID,
               pname: item.PName
            }
            const div = createDiv();
            divRow.appendChild(div);
            div.innerHTML+=`
                <div class="card text-center h-100 mx-auto border-white shadow" style="width: 16rem;">
                    <img src="${baseURL + item.image}" class="card-img-top mx-auto" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5>${item.PName}</h5>
                        <p class="product-price">Price: ${item.PSelPrice}</p>
                        <a onclick=saveProduct(${item.PID}) class="btn btn-danger px-5 mt-4"> Add to Card </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                `;
        });
    } catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
} 

function moveBack(id) {
    shopNcounter = shopNcounter -2;
    getData(id);
}


function handleClick(id) {
    let clickedButton = document.querySelector("#goToItemButton");
    clickedButton.onclick = "";
    getData(id);
  
}


function saveProduct(g) {
  console.log(g);

}
```

Comment: What was the code that caused the error? How exactly did you get "Unexpected end of input"? That usually happens if the code you wrote was incorrect, e.g., missing closing brackets or similar.

Comment: The code in the question won't cause that syntax error. Please update the question to include the code that causes the error. There's nothing special about template literals and variables, the contents of a substitution (`${____}`) can be any expression using in-scope variables (they don't have to be bound up in an object, though they can be).

Comment: Side note: The code in the question **seems** to be using `map` without using the array it returns. That's an antipattern, I've written up why [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/).

Comment: I have just edited the code and included the FULL code. Hopefully, you take a look at it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should not result in the error you see

However you can make your life easier using delegation

1. do this

```js
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = data.map((item,i) => `<div class="card text-center h-100 mx-auto border-white shadow" style="width: 16rem;">
  <img src="${baseURL + item.image}" class="card-img-top mx-auto" alt="...">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5>${item.PName}</h5>
    <p class="product-price">Price: ${item.PSelPrice}</p>
    <a data-id="${i}" class="add btn btn-danger px-5 mt-4"> Add to Card </a>
  </div>
</div>`).join("");
```

2. Have this

```js
document.getElementById("container").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("a");
  if (tgt && tgt.className.contains("add")) {
     const item = data[tgt.dataset.id]
     // here you can add the item
     saveProduct({pid: item.PID,pname: item.PName })
  }
})
```